# Transform .odt document into PDF compatible with Adobe Reader 5 with embedded fonts

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I need to create PDFs out of .odt documents, for submission on an online application website. It is required that the PDFs be "compatible with Adobe Acrobat Reader version 5 or higher, with embedded fonts". Do PDFs created with Libreoffice satisfy these requirements? 
I am using Ubuntu 11.10, LO 3.4.3. The font is Times new roman (but I can change that to a free font if that's a problem).

If not, what other method is recommended?

Comment: PDF created in libre office are ok to view in adobe reader 5 or higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, the pdfs are compatible. You can choose the menu option to export your pdf files if you need more control.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The extra options are useful, one of them is 'embed standard fonts' - I will tick that option even if it's overkill.